# gvim goto file with a PHP constant

Tags: php, constants, goto, ctags

I'm using gvim 7.4 and I'm organizing my PHP project using constants like this :

```
define( 'DIR_HOME', '/');
define( 'DIR_FUNCTIONS', DIR_HOME.'functions/');
```

Now when I include a file

```
include( DIR_FUNCTIONS.'functions.php' );
```

and place my cursor on `functions`, I would want `gv` to go to the `/functions/functions.php` file but gvim is only looking in the current path and I'm getting the following error

```
Can't find file "functions.php" in path
```

I could add all the required folders to the path variable but I'm lazy and I don't want to have to do it for every new constant I'll define. Also I'm afraid it won't deal correctly with files having the same name.

Is there a way (a plugin maybe ?) to make all the goto functions recognize and follow the PHP constants ?

I'm using ctags and my constants are correctly followed when I hit `<C-]>`

I'm sorry if this question was already answered somewhere but after a thorough search I couldn't find any solution

Thanks !